# Weird data type mismatch error VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

This is to do with ranges and arrays, which I find utterly confusing!

I am reading a range into an array variable as follows:

```
Output = Range(Results.Cells(2, 1), Results.Cells(2, 100)).Value
```

where `Output` is a `Variant` array of size 100, and `Results` is the name of the worksheet.

I want to pass this array `Output` as an argument to another sub as follows:

```
DBUpdate (Output)
```

The `DBUpdate` sub is defined as:

```
Sub DBUpdate(Output() as Variant)
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

> Compile error:
>   Type mis-match: array or user-defined type expected

As I understand, I have defined `Output` as an array throughout and I have tried everything imaginable to try to overcome this, but failed. Can anyone here point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: You don't have to specify the `Output` parameter as an array. So instead of `Output() as Variant` just list it as `Output as Variant`.

Comment: @PeterT thanks. I changed the code as you suggested, and it works. But I need to extract the elements of the array that I am passing on the sub DBUpdate - basically I need to join them together to pass as values in an SQL query. Is there a way I can extract them like output(0), output(i) etc?

Comment: @KMLN While changing `Variant()` to `Variant` suppresses the error, it is neither the source nor the correct solution. The correct solution is given in the duplicate question. You can keep the `Variant` though and [access it like an array anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265563/11683).

Comment: @GSerg Read the entire post, but still not clear how I can use the variant containing the whole array and access its individual elements. Can I use a the 'split' method to assign the elements to a separate string array?

Comment: @KMLN from the way you read ranges into your array, it is likely to be a 2 dimensional array with base 1. u can either use `for each vEle in Output strSQL = strSQL & vEle & ";" next vEle` for example, or via indexing like `for i = lbound(Output,2) to ubound(Output,2) strSQL = strSQL & Output(1, i) & ";" next i`

Comment: @AiRiFiEd that worked beautifully, thanks a lot for your help