# VBA - How do I test if optional string arguments are supplied or not?

Tags: excel, optional-parameters, vba

This is a followup question to this:

[VB - How do I test if optional arguments are supplied or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660772/vb-how-do-i-test-if-optional-arguments-are-supplied-or-not)

If my input type is a string (not a variant), is there any way to check if it was missing? The best I found so far is to enter a very unlikely input as my default.

```
Function func (Optional arg As String = "VeryUnlikelyInput")

    If arg = "VeryUnlikelyInput" Then
        MsgBox "NOT SENT"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: That's a pretty fun solution though! (Not 100% perfect, but fun!)

Comment: I tried fiddling around with "On Error Resume Next" and "On Error Goto 0" but I wasn't able to find a solution.

Comment: I don't see a difference from the question you linked to. Is the `IsMissing` test not working for your code?

Comment: @Ross `IsMissing` will return `False`, as the optional argument has a value of `""` when it is not entered.

Comment: I see, I'd suggest using a value that couldn't possibly be passed as the default like a string character that cannot be typed on the keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't supply a default value at all. Then the missing argument will become a null pointer:

```
Function IfDefault(Optional s As String) As Boolean
    IfDefault = (StrPtr(s) = 0)
End Function

? IfDefault()
> True

? IfDefault("aaaa")
> False

? IfDefault("")
> False
```

Note that you can still fool it by passing in `vbNullString`, `TextBox.Value` of an empty TextBox on a form, or `InputBox()` if the dialog is cancelled. `Application.InputBox()` doesn't have this problem of course, since it returns `False` when cancelled.

Comment: Note: An `InputBox` will pass in a null pointer if you hit "Cancel".

Comment: This works in the IDE. If you put `=IfDefault()` in a cell in a Excel worksheet (the OP is explicitely tagged the question with `excel-vba`) it will return `False` as Excel passed an empty string to the function in this case. To make it work correctly you'll have to supply a default value of `= vbNullString` (at least in Excel 365)

Answer (score 0):

If this is for user-entered text use characters that cannot be typed on the keyboard like "¤Þ".

```
Function func (Optional arg As String = "¤Þ")
    If arg = "¤Þ" Then MsgBox "NOT SENT"

End Function
```

Comment: Better yet, `vbNullChar`