# How do I check if an optional string parameter was specified in VBA

Tags: vba, optional-parameters, isnullorempty

I have a VBA `Sub` whose signature Looks like so:

```
private sub xyz (                  _ 
       optional param_1 as string, _
       optional param_2 as string  _ 
)
```

`xyz` might be called like so

```
call xyz("apple")
```

or

```
call xyz("banana", "")
```

or

```
call xyz("strawberry", "blue")
```

I want the function to be able to determine if the caller has explicitely specified a value for `param_2` (which is the case in the 2nd and 3rd call).

I have tried `param_1 is null`, `param_1 is empty` and `isNull(param_1)`, but nothing worked the way I'd have expected it.

So what is the canonical way to check if a Parameter value was specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate of: [VB - How do I test if optional arguments are supplied or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660772/4542428)

The answer Jon gives (IsMissing() for Variants) is what I use whenever using an Optional argument that doesn't need a default value.

More frequently, I find that I prefer to default my optional arguments to something useful.

Answer (score 1):

The last resort possibility would be to specify an absurd default. Then compare with the default.

```
Private Sub xyz( _
           Optional param_1 As String = "mydefault_impossible_value", _
           Optional param_2 As String = "mydefault_impossible_value")
    If param_1 = "mydefault_impossible_value" Then
       MsgBox "novalue_for_param_1"
    End If
    If param_2 = "mydefault_impossible_value" Then
       MsgBox "novalue_for_param_2"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% on this but..
For string do

```
If param_2 = "" Then ...
```

Otherwise for objects use

```
If param_2 is Nothing Then
```

Numbers

```
If param_2 = 0 Then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function OptionalParam(Optional p As String)
    Debug.Print p = ""
End Function
```