# Passing an empty/optional argument to a VBA function

Tags: vba, excel

I was under the impression that if a function has been defined with some *Optional* arguments then you can pass `Nothing` and it will be treated in the same way as "not passing anything at all".

However, I can't make that work. Here's a code snippet that runs perfectly well if all the *"fds..."* variables are not empty but throws *"Invalid procedure call or argument"* if any arguments are `Nothing`:

```
Dim fdsSortOrders(2) As Variant
Dim fdsKey1 As Variant
Dim fdsKey2 As Variant
Dim fdsKey3 As Variant

' ...skipped...

Call loFinalReport.DataBodyRange.Sort( _
    Header:=xlYes, _
    Key1:=fdsKey1, Order1:=fdsSortOrders(0), _
    Key2:=fdsKey2, Order2:=fdsSortOrders(1), _
    Key3:=fdsKey3, Order3:=fdsSortOrders(2) _
)
```

Is there a way to pass an *Optional* argument or shall I make ugly copy-paste code ("`if fdskey2 is nothing and fdskey3 is Nothing Then SortUsingKey1Only`)?

**UPDATE**

This will work since Key2/Key3 and Order2/Order3 are Optional, but I don't want to write three versions of procedure call:

```
Call loFinalReport.DataBodyRange.Sort( _
    Header:=xlYes, _
    Key1:=fdsKey1, Order1:=fdsSortOrders(0) _
)
```

Comment: Clarification: Are `fdsKey1` and `fdsSortOrders(0)` always NOT nothing? Hope you see this soon as I'm going home soon :D

Comment: The're two options: either they contain something useful and good (confirmed with sanity checks) or they're Nothing. I can make them be not Nothing but anything else (i.e. vbNullString).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of function header with optional parameters:

```
Function FunctionName(Optional ByVal X As String = "", Optional ByVal Y As Boolean = True)
```

You need to ommit parameter passing so default value will kick in.
In your example your default values will be of `fdsKey1` and `fdsSortOrders(0)`, so it will sort it by the same key and by the same order.

---

Could not came up with anything else but this:

```
Call loFinalReport.DataBodyRange.Sort( _
    Header:=xlYes, _
    Key1:=fdsKey1, Order1:=fdsSortOrders(0), _
    Key2:=IIf(IsNothing(fdsKey2), fdsKey1, fdsKey2), _
    Order2:=IIf(IsNothing(fdsSortOrders(1)), fdsSortOrders(0), fdsSortOrders(1)), _
    Key3:=IIf(IsNothing(fdsKey3), fdsKey1, fdsKey3), _
    Order3:=IIf(IsNothing(fdsSortOrders(2)), fdsSortOrders(0), fdsSortOrders(2)) _
)
```

Note that at least `fdsKey1` and `fdsSortOrders(0)` should.. well, something.
Alternatively you can make this condition for all 3 Keys and Orders and make default values.
Sorting range by multiple keys with the same value should not affect sorting in any way.

Comment: Thanks AntiDrondert; it appears, however, that you have misenderstood me. My question is: how do I pass an "empty" parametre without omitting it? I.e., in your example, how can I write one call, say, `Call FunctionName( myX, myY)`, and if myX is `Nothing` (or whatever) then the default value will be taken by FunctionName?..

Comment: @Alexander Alright, I think I got your point. Then you will need an entry check in your Sub/Function. Otherwise you can check these variables before the call. This question is **very** related, you should take a look [How do I test if optional arguments are supplied or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660772/vb-how-do-i-test-if-optional-arguments-are-supplied-or-not)

Comment: Well @AntiDrondert the problem is - .Sort is a built-in Method in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` :)

Comment: Aaaaaah IIF! I've forgotten about it! And just yesterday I was sitting and thinking "Give me back my ternary `? :` operator from C++!" I think that your workaround is very elegant. Still not a solution _per se_, but it appears there's simply none... That Micro$oft...

Answer (score 2):

Running a quick test with an Optional Variant, using the `IsMissing` function shows that `Nothing` is not the same as `Missing`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Function IsItMissing(Optional vTMP As Variant) As Variant
    IsItMissing = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    On Error GoTo FuncErr
    IsItMissing = IsMissing(vTMP)
FuncErr:
End Function

Public Sub TestValues()
    MsgBox IsItMissing("Nope") 'False
    MsgBox IsItMissing 'True
    MsgBox IsItMissing(Nothing) 'False
End Sub
```

The problem is that `Nothing` is a Special Object, rather than actually being 'nothing'.  It's like the difference in Excel between a Blank cell and a cell with no data (e.g. `=""`)

I suspect you would want to chain `If` statements with `Is Nothing` to create your sort:

```
If fdsKey2 Is Nothing Then
    loFinalReport.DataBodyRange.Sort Header:=xlYes, _
        Key1:=fdsKey1, Order1:=fdsSortOrders(0)
ElseIf fsdKey3 Is Nothing Then
    loFinalReport.DataBodyRange.Sort Header:=xlYes, _
        Key1:=fdsKey1, Order1:=fdsSortOrders(0), _
        Key2:=fdsKey2, Order2:=fdsSortOrders(1)
Else
    loFinalReport.DataBodyRange.Sort Header:=xlYes, _
        Key1:=fdsKey1, Order1:=fdsSortOrders(0), _
        Key2:=fdsKey2, Order2:=fdsSortOrders(1), _
        Key3:=fdsKey3, Order3:=fdsSortOrders(2)
End If
```

**{EDIT:Following discussions in comments}** *Here is a function which uses 2 arrays to work out which, if any, of the Keys are not Nothing:*

```
Private Function SortNothing(Target As Range, Optional Key1 As Variant, Optional Order1 As XlSortOrder = xlAscending, Optional Key2 As Variant, Optional Order2 As XlSortOrder = xlAscending, Optional Key3 As Variant, Optional Order3 As XlSortOrder = xlAscending) As Boolean
    Dim iArr As Integer, aKeys(1 To 3) As Variant, aOrders(1 To 3) As XlSortOrder
    iArr = 0 'This pointer will track how many non-Nothing Keys we have
    SortNothing = False
    On Error GoTo FuncErr
    If Not IsMissing(Key1) Then
        If Not (Key1 Is Nothing) Then
            iArr = iArr + 1
            aKeys(iArr) = Key1
            aOrders(iArr) = Order1
        End If
    End If
    If Not IsMissing(Key2) Then
        If Not (Key2 Is Nothing) Then
            iArr = iArr + 1
            aKeys(iArr) = Key2
            aOrders(iArr) = Order2
        End If
    End If
    If Not IsMissing(Key3) Then
        If Not (Key3 Is Nothing) Then
            iArr = iArr + 1
            aKeys(iArr) = Key3
            aOrders(iArr) = Order3
        End If
    End If

    Select Case iArr
        Case 3:
            Target.Sort Key1:=aKeys(1), Order1:=aOrders(1), Key2:=aKeys(2), Order2:=aOrders(2), Key3:=aKeys(3), Order3:=aOrders(3), Header:=xlYes
        Case 2:
            Target.Sort Key1:=aKeys(1), Order1:=aOrders(1), Key2:=aKeys(2), Order2:=aOrders(2), Header:=xlYes
        Case 1:
            Target.Sort Key1:=aKeys(1), Order1:=aOrders(1), Header:=xlYes
    End Select
    SortNothing = True
FuncErr:
End Function
```

Comment: OP explicitly said he didn't want `to write three versions of procedure call`.

Comment: Ah - the OP added that in an edit after I had already started writing.  Given that `Nothing` is an object, so is not `Missing`, I don't think there is any other way to do it.  You *could* write a function to accept the range and arguments, and put the 3-version chain in there so that it looks like 1 line in your main code - but only worth doing if you have several instances of this situation

Comment: Yes @Chronocidal, just like AntiDrondert said :) This case is simple but what if the function can take ANY of those three arguments (i.e. Key3 and Key1 or Key2 and Key3)?.. Then it'd be a horrible permutation of IFs IFs IFs :)

Comment: @Alexander Use Arrays and a pointer?  I have added a function into my response, which will fill non-`Nothing` Keys and their orders into an array, and use a pointer to track how many

Comment: @Chronocidal that's a very nice way to check whether a function has any Optional arguments, but still not particularly relevant to my plight, I'm afraid ;)

Comment: @Alexander But, now you can just say `SortNothing loFinalReport.DataBodyRange, fsdKey1, fdsSortOrders(0), fsdKey2, fdsSortOrders(1), fsdKey3, fdsSortOrders(2)` and it will run the sort and automatically exclude any keys where `fdsKey#` is `Nothing` - I though that that was what you wanted?

Comment: Wait wait wait @Chronocidal, I must have missed something. You're absolutely right! Thank you for your time spent on analysing and answering my question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub PassingVariables(ByRef strNotOptionalText As String, _
                        Optional ByRef strOptionalText As String = "Random or Null", _
                        Optional ByRef wbMainOptional As Workbook = Nothing)

' Statements
End Sub

Public Sub CallingSub()

' Here I'm passing just the required parameter (strNotOptionalText).
' strOptionalText will be "Random or Null" as default and wbMainOptional will be Nothing as default.
Call PassingVariables("Name")

' Here I'm actually passing personalized variabled and not using the default Optionals.
Call PassingVariables("Name", "My Personlalized Text", ThisWorkbook)
End Sub
```

Here's an example commented on how to use the code optional parameters. Always remember to put your optional parameters after the required ones.